# Remove subfolder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is the architecture of my website :

```
/
    app/
        index.php
        ...
    libs/
        lib1/
            file.php
        lib2/
        ...
```

I need to access index.php by this url : domain.com/index.php

I tried this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)app 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]
```

It works, but inside my index.php, I call for example :

```
include('../libs/lib1/file.php');
```

It's doesn't work because this path refer to root now...

And I can't access to domain.com/libs anymore, because it's looking for domain.com/app/libs.

How can I do ?

Comment: The `include()` shouldn't matter what the path the browser is using, something else is probably causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include()` shouldn't care what the path the browser sees. That should be based on the local filesystem on the server. But your rules *are* affecting direct access to the libs, so try adding a few more conditions:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^app/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ app/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ app/index.php [L]
```

This makes it so requests for existing files or content won't get routed through the app folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But now if I go to domain.com it's not showing me domain.com/app

Comment: @Iseldore added another rule to handle that.

Comment: It doesn't work. For example,
`<link href="../libs/jquery-ui/css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` doesn't work because it goes up a level too high.

Comment: @Iseldore you're using relative links in your *content* (note this has nothing to do with php includes). You need to change your links to use absolute URL's if you're changing what the base URL is